# slice a 3d numpy array using a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

Is it possible to slice a 3d array using a 2d array. Im assuming it can be done but would require that you have to specify the axis?

If I have 3 arrays, such that:

```
A = [[1,2,3,4,5],
     [1,3,5,7,9],
     [5,4,3,2,1]] # shape (3,5)

B1 = [[1],
      [2],
      [3]] # shape (3, 1) 

B2 = [[4],
      [3],
      [4]] # shape (3,1)
```

Is its possible to slice A using B1 an B2 like:

```
Out = A[B1:B2]
```

so that it would return me:

```
Out = [[2,3,4,5],
       [5, 7],
       [2, 1]]
```

or would this not work if the slices created arrays in `Out` of different lengths?

Answer (score 4):

Numpy is optimized for homogeneous arrays of numbers with fixed dimensions, so it does not support varying row or column sizes.

However you can achieve what you want by using a list of arrays:

```
Out = [A[i, B1[i]:B2[i]+1] for i in range(len(B1))]
```

Comment: This is really neat but its not quite getting me what I want, it keeps returning the error that the slice is invalid. It did however get me thinking and whilst not as efficient I can get it to work within a loop using 'for i in range(len(B1))' followed by out.append([A[i][B1[i]:[B2[i]]]). Its probably not as efficient but it works for what I need. It doesn't appear to be too slow

Comment: I've tested the code myself and found no problems. Are you sure you tried this on numpy arrays of shape (3,5), (3,1) and (3,1)?

Comment: Admittedly, my arrays are not the same shape as this example case. A is (40000,432), B1 and B2 are (40000, 1). I assumed the example I provided would just be a scaled down version, apologies if not.

Comment: It should work anyway, as long as ``B2[i]`` is higher or equal than ``B1[i]`` for every ``i`` (and both should be integers of course)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one *to* [`vectorization`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) -

```
n_range = np.arange(A.shape[1])
elems = A[(n_range >= B1) & (n_range <= B2)]      
idx = (B2 - B1 + 1).ravel().cumsum()
out = np.split(elems,idx)[:-1]
```

The trick is to use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to create a mask of elements to be selected for the output. Then, splitting the array of those elements at specified positions to get list of arrays.

Sample input, output -

```
In [37]: A
Out[37]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]])

In [38]: B1
Out[38]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

In [39]: B2
Out[39]: 
array([[4],
       [3],
       [4]])

In [40]: out
Out[40]: [array([2, 3, 4, 5]), array([5, 7]), array([2, 1])]
# Please note that the o/p is a list of arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired result has a different number of terms in each row - that's a strong indicator that a fully vectorized solution is not possible.  It is not doing the same thing for each row or each column.

Secondly, `n:m` translates to `slice(n,m)`.  `slice` only takes integers, not lists or arrays.

The obvious solution  is some sort of iteration over rows:

```
In [474]: A = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
          [1,3,5,7,9],
          [5,4,3,2,1]]) # shape (3,5)

In [475]: B1=[1,2,3]  # no point in making these 2d

In [476]: B2=[5,4,5]  # corrected values

In [477]: [a[b1:b2] for a,b1,b2 in zip(A,B1,B2)]
Out[477]: [array([2, 3, 4, 5]), array([5, 7]), array([2, 1])]
```

This solution works just as well if `A` is a nested list

```
In [479]: [a[b1:b2] for a,b1,b2 in zip(A.tolist(),B1,B2)]
Out[479]: [[2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 7], [2, 1]]
```

The 2 lists could also be converted to an array of 1d indices, and then select values from `A.ravel()`.  That would produce a 1d array, e.g.

```
array([2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 2, 1]
```

which in theory could be `np.split` - but recent experience with other questions indicates that this doesn't save much time.

If the length of the row selections were all the same we can get a 2d array.  Iterative version taking 2 elements per row:

```
In [482]: np.array([a[b1:b1+2] for a,b1 in zip(A,B1)])
Out[482]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [5, 7],
       [2, 1]])
```

I've discussed in earlier SO questions how produce this sort of result  with one indexing operation.

---

On what `slice` accepts:

```
In [486]: slice([1,2],[3,4]).indices(10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-486-0c3514e61cf6> in <module>()
----> 1 slice([1,2],[3,4]).indices(10)

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

---

'vectorized' ravel indexing

```
In [505]: B=np.array([B1,B2])    
In [506]: bb=A.shape[1]*np.arange(3)+B
In [508]: ri =np.r_[tuple([slice(i,j) for i,j in bb.T])]
# or np.concatenate([np.arange(i,j) for i,j in bb.T])

In [509]: ri
Out[509]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  7,  8, 13, 14])

In [510]: A.ravel()[ri]
Out[510]: array([2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 2, 1])
```

It still has an iteration - to generate the slices that go into `np.r_` (which expands them into a single indexing array)